# Is using Redis right for this situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, mongodb, redis

I'm planning on creating an app (Rails) that will have a very large collection of users - it'll start small but I would like it to be able to handle a million or more.

I want to build a system that will be able to handle 2500+ requests per second. Each request will require a write (for logging purposes) as well as a read from the enormous list of users, indexed by username (I was recommended to use MongoDB for this purpose) and the results of the read will be sent back to the user.

I am a little unclear about how mongo will handle both reads and writes, so I had this idea of using Mongo to sort of permanently store the records and then load them up into Redis every time the server starts up for even faster access so that Mongo doesn't have to deal with anything but the writes.

Does that sound reasonable or is that a huge misuse of Mongo and Redis?

The speed of delivery is of utmost importance.

Comment: How big is *very large* (thousands / billions) ? Do you have more information about your data model. What are you logging? Are your requests mainly reads? It's hard to answer your question without more information.

Comment: Redis can handle that level of requests but you'd probably need to have it sit in middleware before your Rails app.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Redis but I've heard a lot of folk deploying this type of solution and it appears to work so it does sound reasonable.

Comment: lebreeze, can you tell me a bit more about that? The middleware before the rails app? I suppose I should mention that I was planning on deploying this on heroku. Lets say that by "very large" I mean a maximum of about 5 million records; each having a username and a couple of attributes that will be processed by the controller to decide what response the user gets (the response itself will be tiny as well - under a kilobyte for sure, about the same for the record size.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, actually, to create the entire application using just Redis. What you'd want to do is research design patterns for Redis. A good place to start is this PDF by Karl Seguin called [The Little Redis book](http://openmymind.net/redis.pdf).

For example, use Redis's hashes to save all users' information.

Further, if planned well you don't need to have another persistent storage such as Mongo or MySQL in conjunction with Redis as Redis is persistent itself. You just need to pick a good sharding/replication strategy that'll allow you to be flexible enough for future systemic changes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I am reading it right now. I was told by someone a while back that you shouldn't put data into Redis that you can't afford to lose. Your answer suggests that you'd disagree with that?

Comment: Yes. Data in Redis is as prone to loss as data in MySQL. That is, in cases of corruption or crashes. But I can understand where your doubts come from. There is a fantastic article written by Salvatore Sanfilippo himself (Redis inventor) that [demystifies what persistence in Redis means](http://antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html). It provides great insight into the two persistence models in Redis--snapshotting and AOF--and how safe your data is with Redis persistence.

Answer (score 2):

I think the stack that you are asking about is certainly a very good solution and one that's pretty battle tested for high performance sites. Trello (created by same people who created this very site) uses a similar architecture as well as craigslist.

[Trello Tech Stack Writeup](http://blog.fogcreek.com/the-trello-tech-stack/)

[Craigslist also uses this](http://www.slideshare.net/jzawodn/living-with-sql-and-nosql-at-craigslist-a-pragmatic-approach)

Redis is fast and has a great pub/sub mechanism in addition to normal invalidation type features that makes it a superior cache to most.  Mongo is a db i'm very familiar with and think it's great for all sorts of data store purposes as well as being a solid enterprise db that scales well, protects data integrity and checks off a bunch of marks in the SLA enterprise jargon checklist

I think it's a great combination but really the question should be is do I even need this.  For your load I think Mongo itself could handle this quite nicely (and give data integrity) and also if you really want you can run it on server with enough memory to make sure your dataset fits inside memory (denormalizing and good schema design is key).  Foursquare runs exclusively on Mongo in memory.

So think if this is necessary but remember simple always wins.  Redis/Mongo is super powerful but it will also take a lot more work to master two data stores and administer them.

Thanks,
Prasith

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, using a single service makes more sense to me.  There's reason to keep the logging data in memory though.  I'd try using something simple, a logfile if possible, or Scribe or Flume if you need to distribute the writes.